# Purpose of "in" parameters in C#

Tags: c#, language-design, c#-7.2

C# 7.2 introduced `in` parameters for methods. I understand how they work:

```
int MyMethod(in int i) {
    i += 1; // illegal, i is read-only
    return i + 1;
}
```

I undestand that these parameters are passed by reference (like `ref` and `out`).

What I don't understand is the ***purpose*** of the `in` parameters. What do I gain by using them?
I understand the purpose of `out` and `ref` parameters, it is quite useful to be able to assign values to variables in the calling scope, but that function is non-existant with the `in` parameters.

Comment: [C# 7.2 - In Parameter And Performance](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-7-2-in-parameter-and-performance/)

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters: "To pass by reference with the intent of avoiding copying but not changing the value, use the in modifier."

Comment: Also related: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2018/01/08/c-7-series-part-8-in-parameters/. It works as `readonly ref` parameter (cannot be reassigned inside method body).

Comment: c# finally has the c++ equivalent to a const parameter

Comment: I must admit, as interesting as this question is, its more a case of you really just need to read the relevant documentation

Comment: @auburg Also I want to know if `in` parameter is near-equivalent to Java's `static final` parameter.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I believe Java's static final is equivalent to C# readonly

Comment: I've read through these, but I still don't understand the purpose.  Why do I need a read-only parameter if changing the parameter doesn't normally affect the calling scope? To me it looks like the in parameter does the following: 1) Make the parameter be passed by ref, thus changing the parameter will affect the calling scope; 2) Prevent it.    I just can't see what I gain by using it.

Comment: @auburg Sorry, I mean something named "constant/immutable parameters" as Java has. Is this `in` parameter similar to that, in case it passed by reference instead of value?

Comment: @MackThax: using an int (or any primitive value type for that matter) is a somewhat bad example. But if you have a more complex value type/struct the passing by reference avoids copying it. The `in` then additionally provides a safe-guard to accidentally change the original struct. For an `int` the only benefit would be to avoid accidentally altering it, but like you suggest you don't gain much for primitive types.

Comment: So the purpose is better performance when passing large structs?

Comment: Yes, `in` is only providing actual benefit for (large) structs, because in I guess 99% of the cases you want to pass a primitive value type by reference is that you want to change the passed variable itself, which isn't possible with `in`.

Comment: @MackThax C# You could not declare it `method(byval MyReferenceType parameterName)` and that would not be desirable because of a byval would create a inmemory copy of the object. Now it is possible passing a referencetype yet making inmutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"in" Can be used to pass a variable as a read-only reference (value type and reference type both). 
Reason to pass read-only reference is that, if I pass a value type variable without reference, then each time a new copy will be created. So, it will take extra memory and performance will be slower.